Conditional parameter always resolves to undefined
I'm trying to make a value resolver like this:
type Method<TValue, TArgs extends [...any]> = (...args: [...TArgs]) => TValue;

function getValue<TValue, TArgs extends [...any]>(value: TValue | Method<TValue, TArgs>, args?: typeof value extends Method<TValue, TArgs> ? TArgs : never): TValue | undefined {
  if (typeof value === 'function') {
    return args ? (value as Method<TValue, TArgs>)(...args) : undefined;
  }
  return value;
}

But when I try to call it with a function, like so:
function test(num: number): number { return num };

const value1 = getValue(test, [23]);
                               ^^-ERROR

const value2 = getValue<number, [number]>(test, [23]);
                                                 ^^-ERROR

I get this error:

Argument of type 'number[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'undefined'

Does anyone know how I can get the args parameter to correctly resolve to the required array of parameters?

I may be mistaken, but isn't the correct format for an array of x typeArray<x> or x[]? I'm not sure what your [...any] or [number] types would actually result in (though, undefined seems like a reasonable guess at this point)

• It's definitely distracting to use [...any] instead of any[] here; I'd suggest writing type Method<V, A extends any[]> = (...args: A) => V; to avoid distractions. • The actual problem you're hitting is that you don't to make things generic merely by using typeof. The type typeof value is just V | Method<V, A>, no matter what. If you want to test value you're going to have to refactor to something explicitly generic in that type like this playground link. Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write an answer; if not, what am I missing?

@jcalz Thank you, that solved my problem. Create an answer with that and I'll mark it.

In order for your code to work, TypeScript needs to be figure out whether you've called getValue() with a function argument for value or you've done so with a non-function argument for value. You tried to do this by writing typeof value. But the typeof operator doesn't implicitly introduce a generic type parameter corresponding to value. It just tells you the declared type of value. That is, typeof value is talking about the parameter, not the argument.
In your case, then, typeof value is just a union like TValue | Method<TValue, TArgs>, and your conditional type checks it extends Method<TValue, TArgs>. This is very unlikely to be true: it would require that TValue extends Method<TValue, TArgs>, meaning it's some kind of recursive function type; not impossible, but not what you're trying to check. So it will almost always fail the check, the conditional type resolves to never, and the args parameter is of type undefined (since an optional parameter always accepts undefined, and never | undefined is just undefined).
You should so that the function is directly generic in the type of value, and then use that type to determine whether it's a function or non-function and behave accordingly.  Perhaps like this:
function getValue<V>(
  value: V,
  args?: V extends (...args: infer A) => any ? A : never
): (V extends (...args: any) => infer R ? R : V) | undefined;

function getValue(value: any, args?: any[]) {
  if (typeof value === 'function') {
    return args ? value(...args) : undefined;
  }
  return value;
}

Here V is the type of value.  The args parameter is a conditional type that is effectively Parameters<V>. And the return type of the function is another conditional type which is similar to [ReturnType<V>](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#returntypetype) except it evaluates to VifV` is not a function.
I implemented it as an overload where the implementation uses any for the types, so we don't have to worry about the implementation being unable to understand those conditional types. It's not something TypeScript can do currently,  so I'm not even trying.  The implementation is more or less out of scope here.
Let's test the call signature:
function test(num: number): number { return num };
const value1 = getValue(test, [23]);
//    ^? const value1: number | undefined

const value2 = getValue(test(23));
//    ^? const value2: number | undefined

Looks good. If you pass in a function, args is the parameter type of that function, otherwise it's just undefined.  And the return type is either the type of value or the return type of value, depending on whether it's a function.
Playground link to code

I have found a minor issue when using this with arrow functions with untyped parameters. I created another question explaining the situation here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/79203828/16836348
